# Location data, for my own database - mysql

Tags: mysql, api, location, geo

I have a database of cities. One table, 'city' holds over 311,000 cities and data like its region and long and lat, these link to a table 'country' via country_id. What I want to do is add another field in my 'city' table for population and another for area (km squared) then i can create another myself for population density.

My question is, where would be the best place to get a cities population and km^2 online using some kind of api so i can write a script which adds these rows?

I have tried googling and also looked at the google maps api itself. But I think I've hit a wall because I just have no idea where I would get this.

By the way, I got my city data from geonames, and this doesn't come with population already, and as you can imagine I don't want to google over 311,000 cities and manually update it myself.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: maybe US census data?  this begs the question that populations change over time...  you probably want another table with population and date.

Comment: yeah, nice point :) ill take a look now

Comment: i definitely see some spreadsheets on there.. for example: http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/51000lk.html

Comment: Ishould have replied sooner but this isn't really what I'm looking for, I was looking more for population of cities rather than state...

Answer (score 0):

since i located spreadsheet data, and no other comments: i'll post here as an answer :)

http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/51000lk.html

Comment: I delved further into geonames creator maxmind and found this: http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities - I'll take a look and post back what I find.